# How do I change start settings on Ubuntu20.04 and stop it from non-stop start and finish commands and getting stuck while booting?

Tags: boot-repair

Would u please help me sort out ubuntu20.04 as it boots? Seems to run non stop start and finish commands and then gets stuck on ubuntu start page. How can I resolve the problem? Do I need to change start settings? On the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKBc6.jpg)is what I see on the screen

Comment: The image looks like normal, expected behavior. What leads you to believe that it's unusual? Or that "start settings" are related to "*gets stuck on ubuntu start page*?" Are you asking for help with startup settings? Or are you asking for help diagnosing "*gets stuck*?"

Comment: Asking for help with start-up settings at first. Thank you!

Comment: Your output does not show any problems with your startup settings. What do you want to change?